# powershell logic for no of times the value printed then action

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have ps script that checks the system is up or down. Though I have created logic to display the system is up and down. But let suppose if the system is not present, the script will give an error, which we have handled using try-catch and it will print "system not available". I want to count those errors. If the error exceeded 5 times then it should send an email saying the script is not working, also the system not available.

Sample code

```
foreach ($system in Get-Content 'C:\systemScanner\List.txt')
               {

$status = Get-systemstatus $system
write-Host   $system 

  
 if($system -ne <available>){
        
        $badSub = "system is Down"
        $body = "Status of " + $system + ": " + $status
        Write-Host $body
        
        function Get-systemstatus ([string] $systeminfo)
{
    try
    {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        <calling>
    }
    catch [Net.WebException]
    {
        $error.count
        Write-Host "Error"
        [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode

    }
}}
```

I tried this :

```
$errorCount

foreach ($system in Get-Content 'C:\systemScanner\List.txt')
               {

$status = Get-systemstatus $system
write-Host   $system 

  
 if($system -ne <available>){
        
        $badSub = "system is Down"
        $body = "Status of " + $system + ": " + $status
        Write-Host $body
        
        function Get-systemstatus ([string] $systeminfo)
{
    try
    {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        <calling>
    }
    catch [Net.WebException]
    {
        $errorCount++
        Write-Host "Error"
        [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode

    }
}}
 if ($errorCount -ge 5)
 {
 send email code
 
 }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Show us your code x2.

Comment: Hello I have edited my question now.Thank you for your reply

Comment: You could define a variable for `$errorCount` above your foreach and in your catch block increment it `$errorCount++`.  Then after your foreach block check if `$errorCount -ge 5` and send the mail

Comment: @Daniel I tried but error count is not working.

Comment: What is `<calling>` and `<available>`?  I would move the `Get-systemstatus` function out above the rest of your code.  It should be defined BEFORE you use it.  What is the function's purpose?  Will it return a true/false depending on whether the system is available or not?  Or does it return something else?  The email task is happening outside the function so that is where the error counting should likely be happening.  If that's the case I would remove your try/catch block from `Get-systemstatus` or at least rethrow it so that it can be caught again in the code where you are using the functio

Comment: @Himanshu, either place the the `if` statement in the function, or make the variable `$errorCount` global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your function should look like, you should use recursion capturing the number of attempts.

**Note**, this function should work as long as you're sure the **Exception** you're capturing is of the type `[Net.WebException]`.

```
function Get-SystemStatus{
param(
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [string]$SystemInfo,
    [int]$Attempts = 0
)

    try
    {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        
        # Script logic here
        # ...
        # ...
    }
    catch [Net.WebException]
    {
        $Attempts++

        if($Attempts -eq 5)
        {
            Write-Warning "Function failed $Attempts times.`nSending Email."
            
            # Send-MailMessage logic goes here
            # ....
            # ....

            # return at the end of this condition to exit the function
            return 
        }

        Write-Warning "Function failed with Exception: $_.`nRestarting function, attempt: $Attempts"
        # Use recursion until Number of Attempts reaches 5
        Get-SystemStatus -SystemInfo $SystemInfo -Attempts $Attempts
    }
}
```